# Display last record in database using Phoenix/Ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

This is such a basic question that I'm failing to find the details online.

I have a model called 'Radios' and I wish to display the last radio added on to my home page - `templates/page/index.html.eex`

What I have so far:

*radio.ex*

```
defmodule Radios.Radio do
  use Radios.Web, :model
  import Ecto.Query

  schema "radios" do
    field :name, :string
    field :desc, :string
    field :price, :integer
    field :text1, :string
    field :text2, :string
    field :text3, :string
    field :text4, :string
    field :mainimg, :string

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc """
  Builds a changeset based on the `struct` and `params`.
  """
  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:name, :desc, :price, :text1, :text2, :text3, :text4, :mainimg])
    |> validate_required([:name, :desc, :price, :text1, :text2, :mainimg])
  end

  def sorted(query) do
    from r in query,
    order_by: [desc: r.inserted_at]
  end

end
```

*page_controller.ex*

```
defmodule Radios.PageController do
  use Radios.Web, :controller

  alias Radios.Radio


  def index(conn, _params) do
    last_radio = Radio
    |> Radio.sorted
    |> Radios.Repo.one
    render(conn, "index.html", radio: radio)

  end
end
```

*Page Template*

`<p class="title is-4"><%= @last_radio.name %></p>`

I'm assuming I should be writing the query in page controller and not the radio controller?

All of this results in the following console error:

```
== Compilation error on file web/controllers/page_controller.ex ==
** (CompileError) web/controllers/page_controller.ex:11: undefined function radio/0
```

This is probably soooo basic, and imagine I'm missing something very simple, but what!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def index(conn, _params) do
  last_radio = Radio
    |> Radio.sorted
    |> Radios.Repo.one
  render(conn, "index.html", radio: radio)
end
```

You are assigning the result of your query to `last_radio`, but then you are trying to use the variable `radio` when you assign it in your render. I believe you will want

```
render(conn, "index.html", last_radio: last_radio)
```

instead.

Comment: You're correct. That has worked! And if I create further queries, can I just continue to add them in that render array?

Comment: Yes. `render(conn, "index.html", last_radio: last_radio, foo: foo, bar: bar)`. You can assign as many values as you want.

Comment: Great,  Thanks @justinwood.

Comment: @SimonCooper  In addition you can use primary key (which is indexed) for sorting instead of `inserted_at`, e.g. `last_radio = Radio |> last |> Repo.one`
Look at [Ecto.Query.last/2](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#last/2)